# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:translations/app_localizations.dart'

Tags: flutter, pubspec

I made a clone of this project from Github, the project uses localization to support multiple languages. After I cloned the project I went to `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
name: converterpro
description: Unit and currencies converter
publish_to: none

version: 3.2.1+37

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  #Needed to store the customizations and the latest currencies convertions
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  #Needed to open external pages such as GitHub repo, Play Store, etc
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  #Needed for the state management
  provider: ^6.0.3
  #Needed for translation
  intl: ^0.17.0
  #Needed for fonts
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  #Needed for navigation between pages
  go_router: ^5.0.0
  #Needed for Android App Shortcuts
  quick_actions: ^1.0.0
  #Calculator widget
  calculator_widget:
    path: packages/calculator_widget
  #Needed for updating exchange rates
  exchange_rates:
    path: packages/exchange_rates
  #Needed for app translation
  translations:
    path: packages/translations
  #Needed for unit conversion
  units_converter: ^2.0.1
    #git:
    #  url: https://github.com/ferraridamiano/units_converter
    #path: ../units_converter

  flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.21.4
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.3
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  msix: ^3.6.3
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_native_splash:
  # Customize the parameters below, and run the following command in the terminal:
  # flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
  # To restore Flutter's default white splash screen, run the following command in the terminal:
  # flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove

  color: "#eeeeee"
  color_dark: "#333333"
  image: resources/splash/splash.png

msix_config:
  display_name: Converter NOW
  publisher_display_name: Damiano Ferrari
  identity_name: 39826DamianoFerrari.ConverterNOW
  logo_path: resources\images\logo.png
  output_name: converternow-windows
  publisher: CN=E8FE6044-F04C-422E-AC68-EDA83F6AAFB2
  capabilities: internetClient

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true

  assets:
        - resources/images/
```

and clicked on `pub get` to get all the dependencies listed in the pubspec.
when I went back to my `main.dart` file to run my app I stumbled upon this error:[image]
The IDE suggested creating a `app_localizations.dar' file, but nothing happened!
Can someone helps me figure out what is going on and how to solve this error

Comment: You didn't link the Github repository in question

Comment: It's irrelevant, it happened to me in two different projects, the problem Localization

Comment: But here it's the link anyway
https://github.com/ferraridamiano/ConverterNOW/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the README you can find all the [instructions to build from source](https://github.com/ferraridamiano/ConverterNOW#build-from-source-code). The project uses [Melos](https://melos.invertase.dev) for manging the monorepo, so you first need to install it with `dart pub global activate melos` and then bootstrap it with `melos bootstrap`. This command retrieve all the packages and generates the translation code. That's because you got that error about translations.